# How to add a customer to an attribute when registering?

Tags: attributes

I run a music store, selling royalty free music. What I want to do is allow composers to sell their music on my site. I've set up a system that means that people can log in, and add their music to the site already in the account section.

I have in place an attribute called 'Composer' that I'm currently using for myself, but eventually all the composers who sign up will be added automatically to that attribute.

The idea is that on the product page it'll say 'TITLE' by 'COMPOSER', and link the composer to their profile. Their profile will then have blurb about them, and the tracks that they've posted.

I'm think that 'Advance User Profiles' (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advance-user-profiles.html) extension will cover some of the problems, in setting up the user panel.

The process should be:

1. Composer signs up
2. Composers name added to 'Composer' attribute
3. Composer uploads track in user section
4. In the catalog the product should say 'TRACK' by 'COMPOSER'
5. Link on composer, takes customer to composer profile (this depends on mentioned extension above, I know).

What I was wondering was:

- Can anyone give better advice that using that extension?
- Can anyone advice on a way of doing what I've outlined above?
- Thanks a million - I appreciate your help SO much! Anything, no matter how small - It'll still be appreciated.

If it helps my URL is http://freemusicforvideos.com

Comment: Hello Tom Cusack,
I am from Fme Team! The company who’s extension you have shared above,
To make it exactly as you want, feel free to contact us! We do offer customization on extensions to make it suitable for individual clients.
You can contact us either by sending message on official Magento commerce profile or by sending a direct inquiry through our website support / contact us page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not known with the extension you've posted but on the users part.

But for the tracks uploading you will need to create an extension that accepts an MP3 for upload with a price. Then processing the upload creating a new downloadable product.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14728314/387136) seems to contain the code that does this.

Now I imagine you will need to do some reviewing so you might want to mail the admin a product has been created and set it to disabled by default. Also you will probably need to set the name of the composer in an attribute to have some kind of report at the end of the day to know how much any composer has earned.

I know this is all pretty abstract, I hope it helps you a little and if you have any other questions please give a shout.

Comment: Hi Sander - Thanks for getting in touch. So far it's set up so that a user can log in, then:
- Upload a track, set it's price, it's name, etc, etc.
- The track is disabled by default, then moderated (and approved).
- The user has a separate section to receive sales, and profits.

What I want to achieve is on the actual product, have a 'by COMPOSER' under the track title.

I would like to know how I would go about adding their name to the Composer attribute, and how to place that attribute on the product page. The link on their name will be handled by a separate extension, so that fine. Thanks!

Comment: Then you have a lot of work left. Are you able to build an extension like this?

Comment: Eek! I'm okay at understanding and tweaking code, but not at all at writing code. I cannot afford a developer, and am scared that I'm not going to be able to finish the project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hm so reading your comment it sounds like the business end with uploading the track is already build? That's good. Now you should edit the `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and add `<?php echo $_product->getData('composer');?>` under the title

Comment: These requirements have a mix of "reseller" and "customer attributes". As you've found out, Magento only has knowledge of customers and administrators and not "stock providers". There are "reseller" or "market place" extensions for this kind of workflow so do google for those, but the upload feature and associated downloadable product may not be implemented in any of them, so you may end up doing a lot of customization or have the developers of one of those extensions do that for you.